# How to sort array of objects based on descending order of date in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects as below and want to sort it in descending order.

Below is the array of objects

```
[
{
    "attributes": {

    },
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T21:00:00+00:00",
},
{
    "attributes": {
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T09:24:27.179190+00:00",
},
{
    "attributes": {
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T08:54:06.721557+00:00",
},
{
    "attributes": {

    },
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T04:54:56.227415+00:00",
},
]
```

What I have tried?

```
 let sorted_array = this.state.array.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - 
     b.timestamp);
 this.setState({array: sorted_array});
```

But this doesnt work.
Could you someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `timestamps` are normalized for lexicographical sort, maybe you can use [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) on the `sort` method:

```js
let input = [
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T21:00:00+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T09:24:27.179190+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T08:54:06.721557+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T04:54:56.227415+00:00",
  }
];

input.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp.localeCompare(a.timestamp));
console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need to sort in ascending order, then use:

```
input.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp.localeCompare(b.timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp
```

with

```
(a, b) => a.timestamp.valueOf() - b.timestamp.valueOf()
```

(That's if the `timestamp` is indeed a Date object.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create date object of each time stamp and compare those

```js
const data = [
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T21:00:00+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T09:24:27.179190+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T08:54:06.721557+00:00",
  },
  {
    "attributes": {},
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T04:54:56.227415+00:00",
  },
]

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.timestamp) - new Date(b.timestamp)));
```